# web scraping gearbest with python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

EDITIED:
i've been trying to pull some data from Gearbest.com about several products and I have some real trouble with pulling the shipping price.
i'm working with requests and beautifulsoup and so far i managed to get the name + link + price.
how can I get it's shipping price?

the urls are:
https://www.gearbest.com/gaming-laptops/pp_009863068586.html?wid=1433363
https://www.gearbest.com/smart-watch-phone/pp_009309925869.html?wid=1433363i've tried:

```
shipping = soup.find("span", class_="goodsIntro_attrText").get("strong)
shipping = soup.find("span", class_="goodsIntro_attrText").get("strong).text
shipping = soup.find("strong", class_="goodsIntro_shippingCost")
shipping = soup.find("strong", class_="goodsIntro_shippingCost").text
```

soup is the return value from here(the url is each product link):

```
def get_page(url):
    client = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"})
    try:
        client.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error in gearbest with the url:", url)
        exit(0)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(client.content, 'lxml')
    return soup
```

any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide the url you are trying to scrap?

Comment: we need to be able to reproduce the problem so an url is needed here.

Comment: hey guys sorry about that, i edited my question and added 2 urls

Answer (score 0):

You want to use soup not souo. Also, there seems to be a difference between what is returned from request versus what is on the page for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

urls = ['https://www.gearbest.com/gaming-laptops/pp_009863068586.html?wid=1433363','https://www.gearbest.com/smart-watch-phone/pp_009309925869.html?wid=1433363i']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla\5.0'})
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('.goodsIntro_price').text)
        print(soup.select_one('.goodsIntro_shippingCost').text)  # soup.find("strong", class_="goodsIntro_shippingCost").text
```

For the actual price it seems there are dynamic feeds for price in the network tab though it is stored under `actual fee`. So, perhaps there is dynamic location based updating of shipping prices.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

urls = ['https://www.gearbest.com/goods/goods-shipping?goodSn=455718101&countryCode=GB&realWhCodeList=1433363&realWhCode=1433363&priceMd5=540DCE6E4F455639641E0BB2B6356F15&goodPrice=1729.99&num=1&categoryId=13300&saleSizeLong=50&saleSizeWide=40&saleSizeHigh=10&saleWeight=4.5&volumeWeight=4.5&properties=8&shipTemplateId=&isPlatform=0&virWhCode=1433363&deliveryType=0&platformCategoryId=&recommendedLevel=2&backRuleId=',
        'https://www.gearbest.com/goods/goods-shipping?goodSn=459768501&countryCode=GB&realWhCodeList=1433363&realWhCode=1433363&priceMd5=91D909FDFFE8F8F1F9D1EC1D5D1B7C2C&goodPrice=159.99&num=1&categoryId=12004&saleSizeLong=12&saleSizeWide=10.5&saleSizeHigh=6.5&saleWeight=0.266&volumeWeight=0.266&properties=8&shipTemplateId=&isPlatform=0&virWhCode=1433363&deliveryType=0&platformCategoryId=&recommendedLevel=1&backRuleId=']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla\5.0'}).json()
        print(r['data']['shippingMethodList'][0]['actualFee'])
```

Comment: about the price, I managed to get it by myself but you taught my a new way to get it so thank you!    but about the shipping price, in both ways it prints "FREE SHIPPING" even though it cost money..   any idea why is that happening?